# Windows Service problem

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a sample windows service which I got from the following link.

http://an-it-solution.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-make-windows-service-using-c.html

when I try to run the setup file, I runs will and get installed properly.But when I go to

Right Click MyComputer--->Manage--->service.I am not able to find the service there.But when I go to Control panel-->Add or remove programs.I am able to find the installed one there and not in service.Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you haven't done the last thing (from the link you provide)

> Now go to command prompt:-
>
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>installutil
>   C:\WinService\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\WindowsService1.exe

You must install Windows service using *installutil*.

Comment: Running from command prompt I am getting  System.BadImageFormatException:Could not the file or assembly.This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded

Comment: @bharathi that's easy to fix, first check the version of the framework your application uses. Then use *installutil* from that framework. I.e. you might need to change C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ **v2.0.50727** >installutil from **v2[...]** to **v4[...]** (for example)

Answer (score 1):

A service is not the same as a program and shouldent be shown in "Add or remove programs"

If you want to add/remove services use the "view local services" in administrative tools.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you set option "LocalSystem" in properties of serviceProcessInstaller1 component in ProjectInstaller.cs file. It will be visible in control panel >> services only when you set this option. Also you must install Windows service using installutil command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look on the setup and found that the installer just copies the exe to the local system but doesn't installs it.

So if you installed it on say " c:\TestService"

You will have to install it using following commands at the command prompt

cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

installutil C:\TestService\WindowsService1.exe

Then open services.msc you will find a service by the name PingTestService.